# Share 50+ constants between modules in a pythonic way

Tags: python

I understand this is not a 'coding' question but I need a coding solution.

I have multiple packages I wrote, all supposed to be encapsulated, and independent on external parameters other than a few input arguments.

On the other side, I have a general file `constants.py` with 50+ constants which those packages **better** use in order to provide an output dictionary without hardcoded names :

A PACKAGE OUTPUT:

```
{
'sub_name':xyz,
'sub_type':yzg
}
```

Here `sub_name` should be given to the package as input so the general program will know what to do with `sub_name` output.

How *should* I share `constants.py` with the packages ?

The obvious way is to just `import constants.py`, which makes the package dependent on an external file somewhere else in the program.
The other way is to keep constants in some `class Keys` and send it as argument.
Could/should I send `constants.py` as an argument ?

I find it hard to understand how packages should be written and organized when inside a larger project, in a way they can be reused by other devs independently.

Comment: I think the solution to your problem is to use `__init__.py`, which pre-loads all variables/files without importing.

Comment: you mean import it on the __init of the package? then each module in the package has to also import it, AND the package is dependent on external file.

Comment: sorry I do not understand, I am very beginner, can you show a short pseudo code? I will accept it as answer.

Comment: Just to ensure, you want to set some constants globally so that you can load it in any package right?

Comment: yes! I have a packageA, inside many sub packages, EACH need the constants.py, I don't want to import it in each of them.

Comment: Have you tried using env file?

Answer (score 0):

You can store constants in `__init__.py` and import them in submodules.

Example:

`main_module/__init__.py`

```
# inside this file
CONSTANT_A = 42
CONSTANT_B = 69
```

then:

`main_module/submodule.py`

```
# inside this file
from main_module import CONSTANT_A

print(CONSTANT_A)
>>42
```